# Tag merge / synonym request: [assembler] → [assembly]

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Please merge tag [assembler](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assembler) (12 questions) into [assembly](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assembly) (89), and make them synonyms.

Tag *assembler* has no wiki, for *assembly* there is tag wiki excerpt:

> An assembly language is a low-level programming language for a computer, microcontroller, or other programmable device, in which each statement corresponds to a single machine code instruction.

---

Preference for master tag is because it has much more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tags have been merged, this is reflected at [synonyms page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/assembly/synonyms):

> The following tags will be remapped to [assembly](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assembly)
>   [assembler](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assembler)